# Link Windows .obj file with c++ project using NetBeans/GCC/NASM

Tags: c++, netbeans, assembly, nasm

Posted: Mon Nov 22, 2010 2:30 am    Post subject: How to link an assembly object with a c++ project
Hello,

I'm trying to link an assembly program with my c++ program. I'm using NASM to generate the .obj file with the command "nasm -fobj myprogram.asm". The .obj file is created, but I'm not sure how to link this with my project. I tried adding the file to Linker->Dependencies, but I still get the error that my external assembly function is not defined. Maybe the .obj file is in the wrong directory(it's in the root project folder, along with the .cpp files)?

Can anyone give a simple explanation about how to link an assembly language .obj file with my project?

Thanks, 
-KB

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you mangle the name appropriately in the assembler code.
IIRC, __stdcall is used by default in 32 bit MSVC and it prepends an underscore and appends @[bytes of arguments].
So, `size_t strlen( const char *str )`, if compiled __stdcall would be mangled to
`_strlen@4`.

Look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/UsingAsmRoutinesVisualC.aspx) or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46t77ak2%28VS.71%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: The only information that I've found about NASM/GCC indicates that i need to prepend an underscore (_) to the function name in the ASM file.  But that doesn't help.  I have a feeling that I'm not telling NetBeans how to link the file properly, but I'm pretty new to this so I'm not entirely sure.  I did follow directions in a NetBeans forum post that indicated adding the myprojgram.obj file to the linker dependencies will link the file...

Comment: @enoculous Use objdump (or whatever your platform uses to look at obj files) and see what the names are in the objs and post them here as well as any calling convention related compiler switches, stuff embedded in the code etc and I'll see if I can figure it out.